# Anchor clickHandler doesn' t fire event

Tags: gwt, anchor

```
Anchor link = new Anchor("Link");
                link.setStyleName("link");
                link.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                        Window.alert("mes");
                    }
                });
                relhtml.setHTML(relhtml.getHTML()+link);
```

Having this snipset of code my HTML shows correctly, and anchor looks like I exactly want to look like, but the event is not fired. Could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `setHTML`, you are bypassing all of the GWT architecture and just inserting plain-old HTML into your page.  That's why your event handler doesn't work.

The correct way to add a widget to a container is with the `add` family of methods.  For example, you might say `RootPanel.get().add(link)`.

It looks like you are building up an HTML string to insert all at once, but it is OK to just call `add` on every individual component.

```
RootPanel root = RootPanel.get();
root.add(link);
root.add(new Button("And this is a button!"));
root.add(whateverOtherWidget);
root.add(new HTML("You can also add arbitrary html with the HTML widget.");
```

Comment: Assuming `relhtml` is an `HTML` or `InlineHTML` widget, you could also add a `ClickHandler` there and test whether the target element is the link (aka _event delegation_)